# What are some good configurations for MediaRecorder's AudioSource, OutputFormat and AudioEncoder, for small size, portable and reasonable quality?

Tags: android

I plan to integrate audio input into a note taking app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yocto.wenote)

My requirement on the audio input, is as follow. They are listed from most important to less important.

1. **Small output filesize**. Because our data will sync to cloud, we want to keep overall data as small as possible, to save battery and data usage.
2. **Portable**. The output file should able to replay at most platform like iOS, Windows, Linux, OS X.
3. **Reasonable good quality**. I understand higher quality will result larger filesize. Hence, we don't expect a very good quality. An OK quality will be good enough.

---

We plan to use `MediaRecorder`.

I have gone through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats , but can hardly get any idea, what is the suitable ``AudioSource`,`OutputFormat`and`AudioEncoder` we should use?

Can you recommend what is the suitable `AudioSource`, `OutputFormat` and `AudioEncoder` we should use? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But using the following configuration, I was able to generate an OK quality audio. 2 minutes audio length will cost me around 500KB, which I assume is not too bad.

---

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32000);
/*
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
 */
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(RECORDING_MEDIA_RECORDER_MAX_DURATION);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    if (isHeAacEncoderSupported()) {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
    } else {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    }
} else {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
}
```

For `isHeAacEncoderSupported` implementation, you can refer to [How to detect whether MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC is supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770010/how-to-detect-whether-mediarecorder-audioencoder-he-aac-is-supported)